# how to add more details to a Task returned by HttpClient.GetAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Following code is retrieving content from several url asynchronously, and as soon as one content has been downloaded thanks to Task.WhenAny, then it's processed. But in the processed part, I need the Identifier object. I think it's clearer to show you the code:

```
 var downloadTasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        foreach (var identifier in input.Identifiers)
        {
            string url = BuildUrl(identifier, input.PeriodInYear, input.Interval);

            var data = _webRequest.GetData(url, token);

            downloadTasks.Add(data); // Here I only add the data, but not the Identifier. I thought about using a List<Tuple<Identifier, Task<string>>, but then I can't use it with Task.WhenAny(...)
        }

        while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            var finishedDownloadTask = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);
            downloadTasks.Remove(finishedDownloadTask);

            foreach (var content in await finishedDownloadTask)
            {
                // hereI I also need the Identifier object here !
            }
        }
```

Here the code of GetData:

```
public virtual async Task<string> GetData(string uri, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // log removed
        // try catch removed

        string result = string.Empty;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, token).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                else
                    logger.Error("Unable to retrieve data from the following url: {0} - StatusCode: {1}", uri, response.StatusCode);
            }

        return result;     
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that the "build a list of tasks", "`await Task.WhenAny`", "remove completed task from list" approach is very clean.

I find that my code is usually cleaner when I step back, take a look at the code, and write a new asynchronous method that does the "initial" processing as well as the "postprocessing". With your example, it would look something like this:

```
async Task GetDataAndPostProcessAsync(Identifier identifier, CancellationToken token)
{
  var url = BuildUrl(identifier, input.PeriodInYear, input.Interval);
  var content = await _webRequest.GetDataAsync(url, token);
  // Use 'content' with 'identifier'
}

...

var tasks = input.Identifiers.Select(identifier =>
    GetDataAndPostProcessAsync(identifier, token)).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I cover this in more detail in recipe 2.6 of my Concurrency in C# Cookbook.